# Most precise AMP validator?

Tags: css, validation, amp-html

There's certainly a bunch of amp validators online already, and I personally use these 2 - **search.google.com/search-console/amp** and **validator.ampproject.org/**

However, for some reason in a certain cases they will reflect different results [(screenshot here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmzHU.png)

Can anyone tell which one should be trusted? Meaning, which one is more authoritative?

Thanks,
Wadek

Comment: Avoid using images to describe your problem! It's always better to provide code.

Comment: Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, plug-in, tutorial, explain a technique or provide any other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow Stack Overflow

Answer (score 2):

Both validators can be trusted. The problem in your case is that the search console obeys your robots.txt (which restricts the access to your AMPs). Once you provide the Google crawler access to your AMP, the Google Search Console will show the same validation error as the validator on ampproject.org.